# What is the process behind how variables are written over inside a higher order function?

Tags: javascript, variables, callback, higher-order-functions, lexical-scope

After going through the following code carefully, I came to the conclusion that it should log 40. However, the console logs 20 instead and I cannot figure out how x = 20.

Here is the code:

```
var x = 10;

function outer () {
  x = 20;
  function inner () {
    var x = x + 20;
    return x;
  }
  inner();
}

outer();

var result = x;
console.log(result);
```

Let me go through my thought-process:

1. In the global scope, x is assigned a value of 10.
2. outer() runs the function outer. In the outer function local scope, x is assigned to 20.
3. inner() runs, and x is redeclared as x+20. Currently, x is 20, so in function inner local scope, x is now assigned a value of 40. 40 is returned.
4. x is 40, therefore, variable result is assigned a value of 40. Logging result should log 40, instead of 20.

Which step did I misinterpret?

Comment: There are two `var`s, declaring separate variables. Neither of the is ever `40`. Try logging the value of `x` inside `inner`, once before and once after the assignment

Comment: Okay, I did exactly what you said and got undefined, NaN(x+20), and finally, 20. I still don't get how the answer is 20 instead of x+20. Does redeclaring var x inside inner create another variable called x, so there are 2 variables called x, just in different scope, so they don't overlap?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.